# Bootstrap 4.1.0 carousel with Font Awesome controls but hover on controls make them disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I made a carousel in Bootstrap 4.1.0 and used Font Awesome for the controls and css to keep the control just outside the images. When you hover on the left or right control, they controls disappears. Here is a codepen I made too
    https://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/qYEegR
Can you tell me what to fix so the carousel controls don't disappear when hovered or moused on? Thanks

```js
<script> $('.carousel').carousel()</script>
```

```css
.carousel {
  background:#F5F5F5;
}

.carousel-item .img-fluid {
  width:80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.carousel-item a {
  display: block;
  width:90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  color:#036;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  color:#036;
  margin-right: -1rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-controls a:hover {
  color: 004289;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide align-items-center" data-ride="carousel"> 
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="http://nationalkitchencabinets.com/slides/A1.jpg" alt="A1">
 </div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="http://nationalkitchencabinets.com/slides/A2.jpg" alt="A2">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="http://nationalkitchencabinets.com/slides/A3.jpg" alt="A3">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="http://nationalkitchencabinets.com/slides/A4.jpg" alt="A4">
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-lg"></i>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-lg"></i>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `:hover` action and set a different color, right now it's showing but your background is white, that's why you don't see it.

```
.carousel-control-prev:hover {
  color:red;
}

.carousel-control-next:hover {
  color:red;
}
```